# Seeking QGIS version, or plug-in, for distributing QGZ project with simple user-interface and read-only user privileges

Tags: qgis-3, software-recommendations, 3d-model, publishing

I would like to distribute read-only 3D mapping products to the non-GIS general public but am not sure of an easy way to do that with QGIS.  I see how to use Settings to create a customized user profile with limited functionality, but am not sure how to export/transfer this user profile along with my QGZ project file.  Many years ago I used an ArcView publisher software to create read-only GIS products consisting of pmf files and hidden database files.

Does QGIS have similar capabilities?

I'm currently using QGIS 3.10.6-A Coruna.

Comment: What type of read-only functionality do you need? Rather than "read only QGIS", could you achieve what you require with a layout exported as a GeoPDF (this is using standard QGIS), or as an OpenLayers or Leaflet package using the QGis2Web plugin? Would allow user to scroll and choose layers on/off, though less fine control over placement than native QGIS, but also less overhead (regardless of the read-only issue).

Comment: Ah - excellent question.  Here's more details.  The product would be PC-based and portable, utilizing mostly offline data with links to some map servers, so that the product is useful w/o an Internet connection.  It is dynamic product rather than a static map over a fixed area.  It covers an area of about 300 miles x 400 miles and has about 20 to 40 layers that render and label at pre-defined scales.  The user must be able to zoom in/out, turn layers on/off, use the identify tool, use a geocoding plug-in, add a new 3D view, export/print images, etc. I lack knowledge of OpenLayers or Leaflet.

Comment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/36403
Sounds like you want QGIS Reader. Please check out this feature request and add your support, if that is what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, the poster has clarified that he wants a dynamic product with many layers to be selectively rendered, identify tool, export/print images, etc.

I don't think there is a simple "read-only mode", "run-time environment" or "client browser" type solution with QGIS, such as exists for CAD, architectural, or music notation software, for instance. Here is a range of options to explore, each of which will involve some work and tradeoffs:

1. Full-fledged **QGIS** install, with as much **"locked down"** as possible. This would involve elements such as a) simplified user profile, b) `openProject` macro under `Project / Properties / Macros` that disables/traps various panels, menu items, etc., and `saveProject` macro that traps attempted saves, both coded using PyQGIS, d) code that runs at QGIS startup (see https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-python-code-when-qgis-starts), and d) possibly read-only layer files (requires some care!)
2. Possibly complementary to 1), original project file and layer files stored in a **backup somewhere and write over modified versions at startup**, in case user does somehow break out of the restricted usage and accidentally changes something. This could be complemented with a limited number of settings that the user can change and get saved in a "safe" external file via the `saveProject` macro so they *don't* get overwritten from the backup.
3. A **custom Python application** that is invoked by the user, which accesses only the desired **QGIS functionality via PyQGIS**, and in particular doesn't expose any write- or save functionality. This would require some effort and coding, but many of the core elements you *would* want are accessible quite elegantly with PyQGIS (canvas, layouts, etc.)  See https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#python-applications as a starting point.
4. User application runs a **local instance of QGIS Server**, which serves up cartographic information via QGIS Web client (in browser) or, for more functionality, via a "client" QGIS project that fetches its data from the QGIS Server running on `localhost`. See some relevant instructions at https://www.igismap.com/qgis-server-configuration-and-deploying-qgis-project/
5. QGIS outputs data using the `QGIS2Web` plugin, and it is displayed and controlled by the user using **OpenLayers or Leaflet** rather than QGIS. Functionality somewhat limited, but portable. Might not work for OP given desire for 3D views and size of ROI, but on the other hand if the map needs only to be rendered at a small set of predefined scales (esp if they match common tiling scales) it could work well out of the box.
6. Export map as a layout in **GeoPDF** format. Functionality for user is the most limited (essentially: pan, zoom at fixed display scale, turn on layers or groups of layers) but no special software needed for user, just Acrobat Reader or similar.

Answer (score 0):

From a plugin perspective, Lizmaps is something you may want to investigate.
https://www.3liz.com/en/lizmap.html

Even though its a 'web client', it can still work locally. (ie: Not over the internet).
Further to this, there is a course, which mentions 3D web GIS, here
https://www.faunalia.eu/en/training/webgis

This course uses QGIS and Lizmaps, so I can only assume they are using that to do the 3D GIS part, however it might be a combination of OpenLayers and Leaflet.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned above, I don't think qgis2web would work in this instance because of the 3D requirement. How about qgis2threejs?